# AngularJS: How to send html data to php?

Tags: php, html, angularjs, variables, input

I want to send the date seleted on my datepicker input to a php variable, but i don't know how to do it without "submit" form button in angularJS (to avoid reloading the page).

I tried this but without success:

my php code:

```
<?php
require('config-bd.php');

$filtros = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$fec1 = $filtros->fec1;
$fec2 = $filtros->fec2;
?>
```

my html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="desde" style="margin-left: 5px;">Desde:</label>
       <div class="input-group">
        <input name="fec1" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt1"  is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" ng-click="open1()"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="hasta" style="margin-left: 5px;">Hasta:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input name="fec2" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt2" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" ng-click="open2()"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </div>
</div>
```

and my controller code:

```
    $scope.today = function() {
        $scope.dt1 = new Date();
        $scope.dt2 = new Date();
    };
    $scope.today();

    $scope.clear = function() {
        $scope.dt1 = null;
        $scope.dt2 = null;
    };

    $scope.dateOptions = {
        formatYear: 'yy',
        startingDay: 1
    };

    $scope.open1 = function() {
        $scope.popup1.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.open2 = function() {
        $scope.popup2.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
        $scope.dt1 = new Date(year, month, day);
        $scope.dt2 = new Date(year, month, day);
    };

    $scope.popup1 = {
        opened: false
    };

    $scope.popup2 = {
        opened: false
    };
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Create a rest api with php and use angular's `$http`

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post). In general, whenever you have to post some data, you will have to do it over an http post call. You already have the value of dates in $scope.dt1 and $scope.dt2. All you need is to bundle and send it.

The following code will post the data to a placeholder http post url

```
var data = [$scope.dt1, $scope.dt2];
$scope.sendDates = function(){

    $http.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',data)
     .then(function(response){
       console.log(response)
     })
}
```

Similary, to use this in your php code, you need to call the php url. Something like,

```
var data = {date1: $scope.dt1,date2: $scope.dt2};
$scope.sendDates = function(){

    $http.post('someUrl/somePhp.php',data)
     .then(function(response){
       console.log(response)
     })
}
```

And then inside the php, you need the read the values from the request body,

```
echo $_POST["date1"]
```

I have not tried the php code, but it should work. The rest about placeholder post call is tested and working

Comment: Thanks! this was very useful! :)